# Where to download Fabrikam Fiber Call center code base?

Tags: intellitrace

I am trying to download for Asp.Net application for Fabrikam Fiber Call center. It was used by Larry guger in his presentation on http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2012/DEV365  about "Advanced IntelliTrace in Production with Visual Studio 2012". It would be a great help as it is perfect code base to try out all new VS 2012 features at one go.

If this is not the right forum to ask this question please suggest.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download the Fabrikam Fiber demo application from here http://vsarguidance.codeplex.com/downloads/get/379895

The ALM rangers persona and scenario contains a download for fabrikam fiber demo application.

You could alternatively download The VS 20120 ALM VM which contains the labs and all pre-req from here, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/briankel/archive/2011/09/16/visual-studio-11-application-lifecycle-management-virtual-machine-and-hands-on-labs-demo-scripts.aspx